# SQL making a procedure out of a view

Tags: sql, procedure

This is a SQL view that shows how many books are in the same shelf as the book with the ID '2'. Is there a simple way to turn this into a procedure where you can input the book ID, instead of the ID being '2' by default? I haven't ventured into procedures yet, would this particular procedure involve alot of coding?

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books
    WHERE shelf_id = (SELECT shelf_id FROM books WHERE book_id = 2)
```

The subquery is because the Book table has a shelf ID, but the shelf does not contain book ID's.

Comment: Why the subquery?  You are querying both from the same table..

Comment: I've edited the post. It is because the Book table has a shelf ID, but the shelf does not contain book ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Oracle, Try something like below:

```
    PROCEDURE GET_BOOK_COUNT(
        i_book_id            IN  books.book_id%TYPE,
        o_count              OUT NUMBER)
      AS
      BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO o_count  FROM books
            WHERE shelf_id = 
                         (SELECT shelf_id FROM books WHERE book_id = i_book_id );
      END GET_BOOK_COUNT;
```

But better to make it a `function` instead of `procedure` as:

```
      FUNCTION GET_BOOK_COUNT(
        i_book_id            IN  books.book_id%TYPE)
            RETURN NUMBER
            IS
            l_count Number;
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count  FROM books
            WHERE shelf_id = 
                         (SELECT shelf_id FROM books WHERE book_id = i_book_id );
            RETURN l_count;
      END GET_BOOK_COUNT;
```

Comment: In this case I'd prefer a function returning that value directly. Out parameters are sometimes a bit tricky, especially if you want to re-use the result as part of a larger SQL statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agree: Since OP inquired about procedure, I mentioned this. I will update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like this:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBooks(@BookID integer)
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books
    WHERE shelf_id = (SELECT shelf_id FROM books WHERE book_id = @BookID)
GO;
```

That should create the stored procedure you want.